# use windows print instead of browser print directly from link/button

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, printing

Currently we use a print link which uses `window.print();` to start the printing.

Problem is our policy disallows the Google Chrome Printing and the browser crashes.

Printing with `Ctrl+Shift+P` on the other hand works fine but is it possible to use the Windows Printing directly from a link/button?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is `ctrl+p` disallowed, but `ctrl+shift+p` allowed? That seems like an error in your policy.

Comment: Sadly I don't know the policy in detail, Chrome is highly restricted. It's also weird that it crashes the browser. Still, changing the policy involves a huge overhead which could be avoided by using the windows print functionality directly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a solution, if the printable view to be shown as pdf, and the adobe reader has the ability to print it normally. I don't see any other solution how could you invoke the OS print... Probably with IE, and asp.net you can, but i don't think this would satisfy you :)

Kind regards,
hotzu